# I'm using apache client5 fluent, I need to save the MultipartEntity parameter log to the database

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, apache-httpclient-5.x, httpentity

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addTextBody("name", "张三", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN.withCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .addBinaryBody("file", new File("C:\\Users\\123\\Desktop\\QQ截图20231010143306.png"))
                .build();

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        httpEntity.writeTo(byteArrayOutputStream);

        byte[] multipartByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        // save multipartByteArray Log To Mysql

        Request.post("")
                .body(httpEntity);
```

I use httpEntity.writeTo() to turn MultipartEntity into byte[] and store it in mysql as a log record. So when I want to view all parameters in this MultipartEntity request, what method should I use? Or how to turn this byte into LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Part>?

Comment: If you can be certain of the content type (in this case TEXT_PLAIN) you could use ByteArrayEntity https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.httpcomponents.core5/httpcore5/5.1/org/apache/hc/core5/http/io/entity/ByteArrayEntity.html

Comment: Thank you @TheFunk, this is a Multipart type that includes both Text and Binary, just like MultipartEntityBuilder. create(). addTextBody(). addBinaryBody()

Comment: In that case you could use the multipart header. The contentType is just the header for your HTTP request. If TEXT_PLAIN (what you're using above) works then you'd be good to go. You'd just say new BinaryEntity(bytes, TEXT_PLAIN);